# Spring config custom namespace

Tags: spring

I have a standalone spring application with an embedded Apache FTP server. The config looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:afs="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd">    

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

    <afs:server id="server" anon-enabled="false">

        <afs:listeners>
            <afs:nio-listener name="default" port="2222"
                idle-timeout="60" />
        </afs:listeners>

        <!-- other AFS config -->

    </afs:server>
</beans>
```

I would like to load the `port` property of `nio-listener` from a properties files, but

```
<afs:nio-listener name="default" port="${ftp.port}"
                    idle-timeout="60" />
```

doesn't work, since `port` is defined in the xsd as `xs:int`. I'd like to know if there is any workaround (using SpEL?) that will allow me to use the AFS namespace *and* load the port property from a file or from system properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring a few options, I've decided that the easiest way is to step outside the afs namespace for the just the listener configuration. Final config looks like this -

```
<bean id="listenerFactory" class="org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory">
    <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}" />
    <property name="dataConnectionConfiguration">
        <bean factory-bean="dataConnectionConfigurationFactory"
            factory-method="createDataConnectionConfiguration" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataConnectionConfigurationFactory" class="org.apache.ftpserver.DataConnectionConfigurationFactory" />

<bean id="nioListener" factory-bean="listenerFactory" factory-method="createListener" />

<afs:server id="server" anon-enabled="false">

    <afs:listeners>
        <afs:listener name="default">
            <ref bean="nioListener"/>
        </afs:listener>
    </afs:listeners>

    <!-- other AFS config -->

</<afs:server>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `PropertyOverrideConfigurer`.

The problem is that you need to know the bean name that the `<afs:server>` tag define (may be 'server') and the property type that `<afs:listeners>` define (may be a managed list of bean definitions).

Look at STS bean explorer to find correct answers and try whith something like

```
<context:property-override location="classpath:config.properties" />

server.listeners[0].port=2222
```

Other option is disable schema validation setting validating to false before refresh in the xml application context.

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                        new String[] {"applicationContext.xml"}, false);
        context.setValidating(false);
        context.refresh();
```

Comment: I do know which classes correspond to the custom tags, but `property-override` is not a solution since `port` is a constructor arg and does not have a setter. I'm not sure I understand your other suggestion about disabling validation in the application context. Could you please elaborate? The problem here is that the `port` property is declared as an int not only in the xsd, but also in the java class.

Comment: I tried context.setValidating(false), which worked, but it fails in the BeanDefinitonParser, even before it gets to the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. The reason is that the BeanDefinitonParser parses the port property as an int instead of passing it on as String for the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to resolve later.

Comment: This reults in a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${ftp.port}"`. I'm starting to think there is no easy way to do this...